# Change config options on fly in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Explain me important question, please!
I created a Label with list of options:

```
 var labelCombo = Ext.create('Ext.form.Label', {
    forId: 'hostT',
    text: 'My Awesome Field',
    margins: '0 20 0 20'
});
```

Now I need to change config options by event of other component:

```
xtype: 'button', text: 'Refresh', handler : function() {
        //actions here
}
```

I tried to change config like so:

```
Ext.apply(labelCombo, {text: 'New text'})
```

But without success. Is there possibility to change config options by event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the you are trying to change the text value of the label..

if you specify "myLabel" as your label's **itemId**, then you could use

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#myLabel')[0].setText("New text");
```

to update text of the label.